# Application Insights - No screen resolution info

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, azure-application-insights, telemetry

We have ASP.Net Web App with AppInsights. There was ability in Azure Portal to view Session charts with groupping by client **Operating System, Browser, Screen Resolution** etc. But now, with a new version of AppInsights (2.1.0), it seemed that there is no option for gathering any information about screen resolution.

Is there any workaround? Or may be some additional specific configuration options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for this case. You can extend calling **trackPageView** method in your JavaScript code with additional parameters like this:

```js
appInsights.trackPageView(
        null,
        null,
        {
            "Screen Resolution": screen.width + "x" + screen.height,
        });
```

Comment: I have doubt this works anymore? You are using the "Measurement" section, which absolutely wants to get a number.

Answer (score 2):

> with a new version of AppInsights (2.1.0), it seemed that there is no option for gathering any information about screen resolution.

I create an application installing Application Insights v2.1.0, and explore the data from Application Insights portal.

[pic :data and charts in portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWBg4.png)

as you said, we could not find the properties storing about **Device.ScreenResolution** information.

> Is there any workaround?

The [Application Insights API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/) provides calls TrackEvent(name) and TrackMetric(name, value), which enables us to send our own custom events and metrics. And there are equivalent calls for the client side. If you’d like to gather clients’ screen resolution, you could try to write custom telemetry. And you could get screen properties via javascript.